# Cliente consumir Api Rest

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

Agradezco la ayuda, pues no tengo experiencia en el consumo de servicios web Api REst.

Tengo que consumir un servicio, con solicitud de autorización con un token, luego  enviar una estructura json y recibir como respuesta otra estructura json. EStoy usando cUrl en PHP. Mi problema es que no se como  configurar el Header, para enviar el token y luego en que parte envío  el json; Este es el código que tengo:

```
    $url = 'https://sandbox.gw.eu.ebaocloud.com/eBao-Brazil/2.0.0/ws/crearcotizacion';

$ch = curl_init($url);
$token = "Basic YXZarhbnRpiLmRaldjpSdWZnvb5e71cWw="
$token = json_encode(array("Authorization" => $token));
//donde pongo el token?

//attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

//return response instead of outputting
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//ejecuto el POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesita crear cabeceras personalizadas, todo lo que tienes que hacer es agregar a la matriz dentro de la curl_setopt.

De esta manera

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Autorización: '.$token;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset= utf-8';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Te dejo aqui el link con mas información de curl
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Efectivamente funciona.